# R: how to convert a discrete numeric into a continuous numeric?

Tags: r, numeric

when I use `describe()` in **Hmisc** package, it seems for the numeric variables, I got the "Frequency" of each unique value of the variable. But suppose I should get the 5 lowest and 5 highest values.

So is there a way to convert a discrete variable into a continuous numeric in R?